# Magento error when reindexing "Category Flat Data "

Tags: php, magento

I have a strange problem when try to re-indexing "Category Flat Data", I got this error  - "There was a problem with reindexing process."

Here is the exception.log -

```
DEBUG (7): Exception message: Notice: Undefined offset: 162  in /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php on line 833
Trace: #0 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(833): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/user**/...', 833, Array)
#1 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(528): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_getAttributeValues(Array, '1')
#2 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1482): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->rebuild()
#3 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(260): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#4 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#5 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#6 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#7 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#8 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#9 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(223): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/user**/public_html/WEBSITES/*****/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

** I have also noticed that Configuration->Catalog->Frontend->Use Flat Catalog Category is set to "No" and I can't changed it to "Yes" as the option is disabled.

Please help me to solve this strange error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your compilation disabled ? Try to disable you compilation and try re-indexing. ( system -> tools -> compilation )

If still the indexing does not working then again. Clear your cache and lock files ( /var/cache & /var/lock under magento root ) . Then try re-indexing again.

If it fails again then, there might be a integrity constraint error in your database. You have to remove row that violates the integrity constraint and then it would be able to re-index properly.

Use the following to re-index from terminal.

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```